# Can't resize the height of uiView proportional to keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

When I click on textfield, execute this method `keyboardDidShow` and when I started to typing, the view will be go down. What is the reason for this ? Here is my code,

```
else if (textField.tag==2) {

    [self.viewUi setFrame:CGRectMake(0,-110,320,460)];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
}
return YES;

}

- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // Assign new frame to your view
    [self.viewUi setFrame:CGRectMake(0,-110,320,460)];
}
```

Comment: this else if condition where is this called? i think this is called somewhere you type?

Answer (score 0):

Alwin, this particular post might help you in getting this done

[How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)

Or trying adding the `NSNotification` observer at the time of loading of View Controller as in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification
    {
        // Assign new frame to your view
        [self.viewUi setFrame:CGRectMake(0,-110,320,460)];
    }
```